# Return type for Android Room joins

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

Let's say I want to do an `INNER JOIN` between two entities `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Foo INNER JOIN Bar ON Foo.bar = Bar.id")
List<FooAndBar> findAllFooAndBar();
```

Is it possible to force a return type like this?

```
public class FooAndBar {
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
}
```

When I try to do that, I get this error:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.
```

I've also tried aliasing the table names to match the field names, but that didn't work either.

If this isn't possible, how should I cleanly construct a compatible return type that includes all fields for both entities?

Answer (score 74):

Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Foo")
List<FooAndBar> findAllFooAndBar();
```

Class `FooAndBar`

```
public class FooAndBar {
    @Embedded
    Foo foo;

    @Relation(parentColumn =  "Foo.bar_id", entityColumn = "Bar.id")
    List<Bar> bar;
    // If we are sure it returns only one entry
    // Bar bar;

    //Getter and setter...
}
```

This solution seems to work, but I'm not very proud of it.
What do you think about it?

**Edit: Another solution**

Dao, I prefer to explicitly select but "*" will do the job :)
Keep in mind that this solution only works when the fields of both entities are unique. See the comments for more information.

```
@Query("SELECT Foo.*, Bar.* FROM Foo INNER JOIN Bar ON Foo.bar = Bar.id")
List<FooAndBar> findAllFooAndBar();
```

Class `FooAndBar`

```
public class FooAndBar {
    @Embedded
    Foo foo;

    @Embedded
    Bar bar;

    //Getter and setter...
}
```

edit: since Version 2.2.0-alpha01, room @Relation annotation can manage One-To-One relation

Comment: If there are conflicts between `Foo` and `Bar`, I believe you can eliminate these by creating a subset representation of the latter class, e.g. `public class BareBar { ...some bar fields... }`, and then adding `entity = BareBar.class` to the `@Relation`. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html

Comment: Second solution causes "Multiple fields have the same columnName" compile error then entities have PK property named the same: id

Comment: Does the second solution actually work? Coz I am getting "Cannot figure out how to convert Cursor..." error. Additionally I am using `@Embedded(prefix = "foo_")` & `@Embedded(prefix = "bar_")`

Comment: @musooff The second solution only works for me when there is no `prefix` value set on the `@Embedded`s. To workaround duplicate column names I had to use `@ColumnInfo(name = ...)` for each class field on each table.

Comment: For second solution: which is 1 `Foo` & 1 `Bar` return. You can try to `@Embedded` `Bar` and `@Relation` `Foo` to list. Then do the usual `Select * From Bar`. It gives you 1:1, even entities has same field names. If ever you need a certain `Foo` you can use `JOIN` on it's query. 

Cheers.

Comment: There is a good explanation in the room documentation for relationsships: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Relation.html

Comment: this link helped https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many

Comment: For those who need to use @Embedded with a prefix, it is necessary to add the prefix when performing Query, otherwise rows from tables with the same name will not receive correct values.
This is a good explanation:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50698610/6754909

Comment: Does the first option work with LiveData or Observable? I would prefer the second option, but can't because of repeating id names.

Comment: An additional insight is that if you only wish to do a `LEFT JOIN`, you do not need to include that statement; Room will left join on your behalf. Doing so explicitly sets columns with the same name to their default values.

Answer (score 19):

Another option is to just write a new POJO representing the resulting structure of your JOIN query (which even supports column renaming to avoid clashes):

```
@Dao
public interface FooBarDao {
   @Query("SELECT foo.field1 AS unique1, bar.field1 AS unique2 "
          + "FROM Foo INNER JOIN Bar ON Foo.bar = Bar.id")
   public List<FooBar> getFooBars();

   static class FooBar {
       public String unique1;
       public String unique2;
   }
}
```

See: [room/accessing-data.html#query-multiple-tables](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data.html#query-multiple-tables)

Comment: This works when fields have same names, just need to have an alias for them.

Answer (score 13):

Try this way.
For example, I have M2M (many-to-many) relations between `Product` and `Attribute`. Many *Products* have many *Attributes* and I need to get all *Attributes* by `Product.id` with sorted records by `PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES.DISPLAY_ORDERING`.

```
|--------------|  |--------------|  |-----------------------|
| PRODUCT      |  | ATTRIBUTE    |  | PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES   |
|--------------|  |--------------|  |-----------------------|
| _ID:  Long   |  | _ID: Long    |  | _ID: Long             |
| NAME: Text   |  | NAME: Text   |  | _PRODUCT_ID: Long     |
|______________|  |______________|  | _ATTRIBUTE_ID: Long   |
                                    | DISPLAY_ORDERING: Int |
                                    |_______________________|
```

So, models will be like below:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "PRODUCTS",
    indices = [
        Index(value = arrayOf("NAME"), unique = true)
    ]
)
class Product {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_ID")
    var _id: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "NAME")
    @SerializedName(value = "NAME")
    var name: String = String()

}


@Entity(
    tableName = "ATTRIBUTES",
    indices = [
        Index(value = arrayOf("NAME"), unique = true)
    ]
)
class Attribute {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_ID")
    var _id: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "NAME")
    @SerializedName(value = "NAME")
    var name: String = String()

}
```

And the "join" table will be:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES",
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["_PRODUCT_ID", "_ATTRIBUTE_ID"])
    ],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = Product::class, parentColumns = ["_ID"], childColumns = ["_PRODUCT_ID"]),
        ForeignKey(entity = Attribute::class, parentColumns = ["_ID"], childColumns = ["_ATTRIBUTE_ID"])
    ]
)
class ProductAttribute {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_ID")
    var _id: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "_PRODUCT_ID")
    var _productId: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "_ATTRIBUTE_ID")
    var _attributeId: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "DISPLAY_ORDERING")
    var displayOrdering: Int = 0

}
```

In, `AttributeDAO`, to get all attributes based on `Product._ID`, you can do something like below:

```
@Dao
interface AttributeDAO {

    @Query("SELECT ATTRIBUTES.* FROM ATTRIBUTES INNER JOIN PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES ON PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES._ATTRIBUTE_ID = ATTRIBUTES._ID INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTS._ID = PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES._PRODUCT_ID WHERE PRODUCTS._ID = :productId ORDER BY PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES.DISPLAY_ORDERING ASC")
    fun getAttributesByProductId(productId: Long): LiveData<List<Attribute>>

}
```

If you have any questions, please tell me.

Comment: This query is quite may result in freezing the app when data in both tables crosses 1000. Will you suggest me how to avoid freezing the app when query grows and return result grows @dphans

Comment: @SureshMaidaragi Use with paging library. Now change return query from `LiveData<List<Attribute>>` into `DataSource.Factory<Int, Attribute>`. Otherway, use `LIMIT` page size from query.

Comment: Why do you use `@SerializedName`?

Comment: I do have a question about ManyToMany and RoomDB: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69907356/3692177)

Comment: @CoolMind sorry that annotation is no need (`@SerializedName`) :D

Comment: @dphans, well, you can edit the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to force a return type like this?

You can try `@Embedded` annotations on `foo` and `bar`. That will tell Room to try to take the columns from your query and pour them into `foo` and `bar` instances. I have only tried this with entities, but the docs indicate that it should work with POJOs as well.

However, this may not work well if your two tables have columns with the same name.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work since my entities have columns with the same name (like `id`)...

Comment: @pqvst: "how should I cleanly construct a compatible return type that includes all fields for both entities?" -- either pick `foo` or `bar` to be `@Embedded` and put the remaining fields directly in `FooAndBar`, or put all fields directly in `FooAndBar`. Use `AS` in the SQL to rename duplicate columns in the result set, and use `@ColumnInfo` as needed to map those `AS`-renamed columns into what you want the fields to be.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid having to do... Doesn't feel very "clean" to me :/

Comment: @pqvst: As it stands, your query should result in either a SQLite error about duplicate columns in the output, or at best the `Cursor` that `SQLiteDatabase` creates under the covers will not have both `id` columns (and any other duplicated columns). You need all the columns in a SQL query to have distinct names in the result set, otherwise the `Cursor` will not have all the data. Once you fix that, adjust the `Foo` and `Bar` entities to match and use the `@Embedded` solution.

Comment: @pqvst: "Doesn't feel very "clean" to me" -- then get rid of the `JOIN` and make two DAO calls, one to get the `Foo`, the other to get the associated `Bar`. The express intention with Room is that arbitrary queries result in arbitrary POJOs for the output, much as how you need appropriate POJOs for Retrofit calls. Entities are there mostly for plain CRUD.

Comment: @pqvst have you get the solution for that problem?

Comment: @adri1992 No. I created a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63621744

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much @pqvst =)

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi sir, can you give me some advice ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305882/combine-data-from-two-tables-in-room-viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

This is my Food Table

```
@Entity(tableName = "_food_table")
data class Food(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
            @ColumnInfo(name = "_food_id")
            var id: Int = 0,
            @ColumnInfo(name = "_name")
            var name: String? = "")
```

This is my Cart table and model class (Food Cart)

```
@Entity(tableName = "_client_cart_table")
data class CartItem(
                @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
                @ColumnInfo(name = "_food_id")
                var foodId: Int? = 0,
                @Embedded(prefix = "_food")
                var food: Food? = null,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "_branch_id")
                var branchId: Int = 0)
```

Note: Here we see _food_id column in two table. It will throw compile time error. From @Embedded doc, you have to use prefix to differentiate between them.

Inside dao

```
@Query("select * from _client_cart_table inner join _food_table on _client_cart_table._food_id = _food_table._food_id where _client_cart_table._branch_id = :branchId")
fun getCarts(branchId: Int) : LiveData<List<CartItem>>
```

This query will return data like this

```
CartItem(foodId=5, food=Food(id=5, name=Black Coffee), branchId=1)
```

I have done this in my project. So Give it a try. Happy coding