# Android Room one-to-one Entities Relation

Tags: java, android, android-room

In Room if you want a relation between two entities you can achieve it with a third `POJO` that defines their relation as:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
  //fields here including _id,...
}

@Entity // forigne keys restriction here ...
class Baz {
   long foo_id
}

//The linking POJO
class BazWithFoo extends Baz { //may replaced with @Embeded Baz field 

   @Relation(entity = Foo.class,entityColumn = "_id",parentColumn = "foo_id")
   List<Foo> foo; // <-- want this to be Foo not List<Foo>
}
```

Is there a nice approach to make the POJO expose a single field instead of a `List`? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059942/return-type-for-android-room-joins/45327253#45327253).
It's possible to manage two `@Embedded` in your POJO

Comment: thank you, the Edit part of that answer helped, am still looking for at least a work around _inheritance or encapsulation_ for the List field to deal with as a one object not collection, _until there is a clean solution_

Comment: Does it update the parent query if you update the foreign item?