# How to select model with its 1:1 relation with ROOM?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

Let's assume the following simple schema:

```
Item | item_id, category_id, name
Category | category_id, name
```

With room, it could be described with the following entities.

```
@Entity(tableName = "item", foreignKeys = {/* fk to category */})
public class Item {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_id")
    public final int itemId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id", index = true)
    public final int categoryId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public final int name;

    // constructor setting the properties is omitted
}


@Entity(tableName = "category")
public class Category {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id")
    public final int categoryId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public final String name;

    // constructor setting the properties is omitted
}
```

How to obtain a POJO that would contain both the `Item` and it's `Category`, preferably with a single query?

This is the closest I've managed to get:

```
public class ItemWithCategory {
    public Item item;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "category_id", entityColumn = "category_id")
    public List<Category> category;
}

// this is in my @Dao
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id = :itemId")
abstract Flowable<ItemWithCategory> getItemWithCategory(int itemId);
```

I don't like my solution because:

1. Internally room performs two queries in a transaction, for something that hopefully can be obtained with a single one.
2. [The relations must be a `List` or `Set` even in 1:1 relations](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62905145), which is confusing and requires writing unnecessary checks and comments. However, the same post says that it could be done with a join query but doesn't say how!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059942/return-type-for-android-room-joins) might help you

Comment: @ReneFerrari thanks, however, I already saw and tried that. You can not do `@Embedded` of two models in a POJO if they have overlapping column names (like in the case above - `name`). ROOM complains on compile time.

Comment: My guess is that the `JOIN` solution theorized in that issue comment is the one that Rene pointed out. That may not work in your case, but that does not mean that the approach is unusable in general. I don't know of an improvement over Rene's, beyond simply not dealing with the entity much and converting it to a model object for use in your UI layer.

Comment: "for something that hopefully can be obtained with a single one" - a single query is not an improvement in the abstract. For this case, it might be. But, suppose that you have 10,000 items, and category has 100 columns... but all items are in one category. You'd retrieve nearly 1,000,000 extra values, as your `JOIN` would return duplicate information for that single category for all 100 columns across all 10,000 items. That's likely to perform substantially worse than would two queries in a transaction.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are completely right for such a hypothetical situation. However, in the presented question I do not have a related table with 100 columns, nor am I trying to select 10,000 items - in fact, I'm trying to select one specific item with its category (which is guaranteed to be non-null). Also, I'd be happy with a solution that performs two queries internally, if my single related category didn't have to be contained in a `List`.

Comment: "in the presented question I do not have a related table with 100 columns, nor am I trying to select 10,000 items" -- sure, but the Room engineers don't really know that. "I'd be happy with a solution that performs two queries internally, if my single related category didn't have to be contained in a List" -- as I noted in my first comment, I'm not aware of a solution for that, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed your first comment and that's a fair answer, thank you! Hopefully, ROOM engineers will allow for a more elegant solution in a future version. I'm already converting the entities to domain models but still, it felt hacky.