# How to apply condition to a relation, or how to properly handle JOIN queries with WHERE clause in Room?

Tags: android, android-room, pojo, relation, android-livedata

Please bear with me, i'm new to architecture components and android in general.
My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005681/room-relations-with-conditions#50698610) but unfortunately the accepted answer doesn't seem to work.
I have an example one to many relation like in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330452/android-persistence-room-cannot-figure-out-how-to-read-this-field-from-a-curso/44424148#44424148). My example database has two tables USERS and PETS as shown in the following images:

[image: 1][image: 2]

Let's say I want to get a list of users containing a list of their pets grouped by user id **only** with pets younger than 5. 
The result should look like this (pseudo code):

{uId: 2, [Pet3, Pet4]; uId: 4, [Pet6, Pet7];}

Another requirement is that the Dao needs to return the list as a LiveData object because I'm using MVVM architecture and want it to be Lifecycle aware and observable.

With these requirements, the **UserDao** would look like this:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(User user);

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT USERS.uId, PETS.pId , PETS.userId, PETS.age " + 
    "FROM USERS INNER JOIN PETS ON PETS.userId = USERS.uId " +
    "WHERE PETS.age < 5 " +
    "GROUP BY USERS.uId")
    LiveData<List<UserWithPets>> getUserPets();

}
```

**User** Entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id; // User id
}
```

**Pet** Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Pet {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;     // Pet id
    public int userId; // User id
    public int age;
}
```

The problem is now: how should i design the UserWithPets that room understands it and maps the cursor the way i want?
Here is what i tried so far:

### Approach 1:

The most convenient way in my opinion would be using a Relation, like in the POJO below.

**UserWithPets** POJO:

```
public class UserWithPets {
    @Embedded
    public User user;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "userId", entity = Pet.class)
    public List<Pet> pets; 

}
```

Unfortunately, the functionality to assign a condition to a relation is not yet implemented by google. So we always get a full list of pets for every user that owns a pet younger than 5. Hopefully this will be possible soon, since the feature request is already assigned [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65509934) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112665535).

Statement from google from [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63621744) feature request:  "we are planning to implement some query rewriting logic to fix these, not for 2.1 but hopefully in 2.2 where we'll focus more on relations."

### Approach 2:

Another option would be Embedding both, User and Pet like:

```
public class UserWithPets {
    @Embedded
    public User user;

    @Embedded
    public Pet pet;

}
```

This doesn't work either, because now we only get 1 pet per user.

### Approach 3:

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50698610/11278807) suggests to just create a merged class that extends from user like:

```
public class UserWithPets extends User {

    @Embedded(prefix = "PETS_")
    List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I tried in many ways, with contructor and without, but i can't get it to work. it always gives errors like "Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - java.util.List"
or
The query returns some columns ... which are not used by UserWithPets. So any advice is welcome here.

### Approach 4:

Just make two queries and stitch the results together. How would i do that using LiveData? Where should the joining operation be done? I can't do it in the Activity, that's not the point of an MVVM pattern. And not in the repository or viewmodel, since LiveData is immutable. Or is there another way?

What would be a working solution to get a result with the above requirements?