# Room one-to-many relation with conditions on both tables

Tags: android, database, android-room, androidx, android-jetpack

I am trying to implement a Room database using a one-to-many relation, following the Android Room training (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many).

However, I can't find a way to add a condition on the second table.

For example, to fetch all UserWithPlaylists, for users above 25 and having playlists names starting with "play" this does not work because Room does not automatically group the results (and a `GROUP BY` clause prevents creating the List of Playlist):

```java
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT User.* FROM User, Playlist WHERE User.age > 25 AND Playlist.playlistName LIKE play%")
public List<UserWithPlaylists> getUsersWithPlaylistsSpecific();
```

I already tried solutions such as embedding one entity in another and using
`@Embedded(prefix = "PETS_")`
as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50698610 but without success.
I also want to avoid [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56067948) using a Java Map.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The `@Embedded` solution with a table join is probably your best bet.  `@Relation` doesn't allow you to add your own conditions on the completely separate query Room runs to retrieve the playlists for `UserWithPlaylists`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's too bad. This is what I did finally, with a mix of a loop solution for removing unwanted entities.
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

`@DatabaseView` works like a normal `@Entity` when querying it. So you can:

```
@DatabaseView("""
  SELECT * FROM Playlist
  WHERE Playlist.playlistName LIKE play%
""" )
data class Playlist2(...)

data class UserWithPlaylist2s(
  @Embed
  val user: User
  @Relation(...)
  val playlists: List<Playlist2>
)
```

However, the inconvenience is that you can't add parameters into `@DatabaseView`. So that the query condition on the 2nd table must be a compile time constant.