# Querying table A with inner join on table B does not return columns from table B in an Android application using Room database

Tags: android, inner-join, relationship, android-room

I'm trying to query from `posts` table with inner join on `users` and its respective primary and foreign key:

```
@Query("SELECT p.*, u.id AS userId, u.name AS userName, u.username AS userUsername FROM posts p JOIN users u ON p.userId = u.id")
fun fetchAllPostsAndUsers(): Observable<List<Post>>
```

These are the POJOs. First, `User`:

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @SerializedName("id")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val uid: Int,

    val name: String,

    val username: String,

    val email: String,

    @Embedded
    val address: Address?,

    val phone: String,

    val website: String,

    @Embedded
    val company: Company?
)
```

and `Post`:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "posts",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = User::class,
        parentColumns = ["id"],
        childColumns = ["userId"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class Post(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @SerializedName("id")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val pid: Int,

    val userId: Int,

    val title: String,

    val body: String
)
```

But the result of the query above is only the columns from the `posts` table, without any column from the `users`', despite being included in the query when fetching from the database.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. What exactly does "result is a list of Post without any User information" mean & what was the output & the input?

Comment: There is no input because it is a function that fetches from the database. The output is this query fetching only the `posts` columns without the `users`', but in the query, I am also including `user.name` and `user.username`, but these two columns don't appear in the results when I `Log` it.

Comment: How am I going to put runnable code here? Just create a new Android application and make use of the code yourself, then.

Comment: The point is you haven't given all the necessary info to recreate in a generic setup--namely a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should take a look to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45327253/7813012).
`Post` entity do not contain any `User` object. You should create a model that hold both.

Comment: Hi, I cannot click on the link. There is no anchor.

Comment: Hi, it's ok now ^^'

Comment: Interesting one. I will try it. I do not know how I did not find it.

Comment: I guess I am almost there. I am receiving a compiler error saying **The columns returned by the query does not have the fields**, showing a few fields, and the error ends with **Columns returned by the query: [title,body,name,username]**, the ones I am actually trying to query.

Comment: I created a `PostWithUser` class and `Embedded` both `User` and `Post` data classes prefixed with `user_` and `post_` respectively. Creating an alias on the SQL query with these prefixes do not solve the problem. What do I do?

Comment: It's the first block of code in the question. You may also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834419/the-columns-returned-by-the-query-does-not-have-the-fields-columns-returned-by

Comment: Try this :
`SELECT p.*, u.* FROM posts p JOIN users u ON p.userId = u.id`

Comment: Please, take a look at my new question. There show my attempts and this was one of them.

Comment: I found the solution. In the `PostWithUser`, I need to add fields of the same name of the columns or alias I am querying. No embedded whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was to add fields matching the name of the columns or alias from the SQL query, and not these `@Embedded`s.