# Room: Grab dao selected data in function body and return after extra processing

Tags: android, android-room

I have a DAO with a select. I would like to get a hold of the selected data in order to process it further before returning to the Repository:

```
@Dao
interface OfferDao {
    ...
    @Query("select * from offer")
    fun getOffers(): LiveData<List<Offer>> {
        // get a hold of the data
        // process it some more
        // return offers to caller (repository)
    }
```

Here is the `Offer` entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "offer")
data class Offer(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var flightIndex: Int = 0,
    var price: Double = 0.0,
    var ticketClassIndex: Int = 0,
    var ticketClass: String = "",
    var supplier: String? = null,
    @Ignore
    var flight: Flight? = null
)
```

The extra processing has to do with fetching and attaching a `Flight` entity to the Offer. In the body of the `getOffers` function I'd like to fetch the Flight by the `flightIndex` and attach it to the Offer before sending back to the repository.

Comment: I think you should do this in the `ViewModel` class and not in the DAO

Comment: I'd love to do it in the repository, but then the extra processing needed, won't be included in LiveData delivered to the UI. That's why I thought of doing that in the dao to make sure the LiveData fetched will be complete.

Comment: The `getOffers` method should be the same for all the callers. This personalization is something which should reside in the `ViewModel` because maybe another consumer of this query won't need this. Can you explain which processing you want to perform?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the post with description of what I'd like to do in the body of `getOffers`.

Comment: I think you should go with a JOIN. Have you checked something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45327253/2910520

Comment: I'd really like to have the Flight as an object inside Offer and not flat. I thought of doing this in the dao function (if possible) also because I have a couple of cases with a list of indices which I would like to attach as objects. Example: The Flight entity has a list of  segment ids. Here I want to attach a list of Segment Entity objects to the Flight entity.

Comment: I dont think you can do this at the DAO level. If you are sure you can't do it with JOINs you need to apply [Transformations](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata) to the `LiveData` object in the `ViewModel` to get exactly what you want

Comment: Yes, this will probably be the only way out.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to try something like that

```
@Dao
interface OfferDao {
    @Query("select * from offer")
    fun getOffers(): LiveData<List<Offer>> 

    fun getOffersWithFlight(): LiveData<List<Offer>> = getOffers().apply{ forEach { it.flight = GETFLIGHT(it.flightIndex)}}

}
```

note: I know that isn't working code, but just a sample