# I cannot figure out how to include a WHERE clause in an Android Room @Query annotation query where multiple table queries are necessary

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I need to convert a standard SQL query into a `@Query` annotation for use with Room, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I have three tables ...

**AccessList**

```
ID INTEGER
ListName TEXT
Active INTEGER
```

**Enrollment**

```
ID INTEGER
FirstName TEXT
LastName TEXT
```

**AccessListEnrollmentMapping**

```
ID INTEGER
AccessListID INTEGER
EnrollmentID INTEGER
```

An Enrollment can be on more than one AccessList and AccessLits can be active [1] or not active [0], so here is an example SQL query that **does work** when using DB Browser for SQLite:

```
select * from Enrollment where ID in (select EnrollmentId from AccessListEnrollmentMapping where AccessListId IN (SELECT ID FROM AccessList WHERE ID < 4 AND Active = 1));
```

And here is my `@Query` annotation:

```
@Query("select * from Enrollment where ID in (select EnrollmentId from AccessListEnrollmentMapping where AccessListId IN (:accessListIds))") // NEED TO CHECK FOR AccessList.Active == 1
public abstract List<Enrollment> selectEnrolleesPerAccessLists(List<Long> accessListIds);
```

This query, however, returns all Enrollments on active and inactive AccessLists. I cannot figure out how to include the `where AccessList.Active = 1` in the annotation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059942/return-type-for-android-room-joins

you'll want to look at using Room's @Relation protocol, or do traditional join

Comment: I'm not doing a `JOIN`, though.

Comment: I think the point is that you need to switch to `JOIN`.