# Exactly ONE TO ONE Relation in Room

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I believe it have been asked several times but no working solution.

Room has `@Relation` annotation which is used for one to many relationships. That's basically if you have `User` and `Pet` models, as `User` can have several `Pet`s, `@Relation` annotation works perfectly as return type of `Pet`s are list (or set).

```
class UserAndAllPets : User() {
   @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "userId")
   var pets: List<Pet> = arrayListOf()
 }
```

The problem is what if in my case `User` and `Pet` is one to one related. As in every user can have one pet. That means there is no point of using `@Relation` as it only supports list or set return types. And it's totally inefficient to use as a list, even if I use it. So I am looking for a exact one to one relation where I can get a result of

```
class UserAndPet {
    var user: User? = null
    var pet: Pet? = null
}
```

I have tried tried several was as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45327253/8412192) method (which has lots of upvotes, but it doesn't work). 
Supposedly,

```
class UserAndPet {
    @Embedded
    var user: User? = null
    @Embedded
    var pet: Pet? = null
}
```

Should work, but I am getting

> Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (UserAndPet)

There is no conflict as I already use `prefix` for `@Embedded` fields.

And please, can you not redirect my to any other post on stack overflow, as I tried all but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature has been added as of `2.2.0-alpha01` of room.

Ref - [Room release 2.2.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.2.0-alpha01)

Comment: On room 2.2.5 and it's not working. I get the error `error: Fields annotated with @Relation must be a List or Set.
`

Answer (score 0):

When we considering `1 to 1` relationship below approach is also possible and for more please follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45327253/4238189).

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
class User(
  val id: Int
  // ...
) {

  @Ignore /* Ignores the marked element from Room's processing logic. */
  var pet: Pet? = null
}

@Entity(tableName = "pet")
class Pet(
  val id: Int,
  val userId: Int
)

/* Single task used for 1 to 1 read */
class UserWithPetReadTask : RxTask.CallableWithArgs() {

  private var result = UserWithPetTaskResult()
  override fun call(params: Array<out Any>?): Any {

    App.mApp?.getDBLocked { appDb ->

      /* Read user details from repo */
      val user: User? = appDb?.getUserDao()?.getUserById("[userId]")
      user.let {
        /* Read pet associated and assign it to user*/
        it?.pet = appDb?.getPetDao().getPetAssociated("[userId] or [user?.id]")

        result.user = user
        result.isSuccess = true
      }
    }
    return result
  }
}

class UserWithPetTaskResult {
  var isSuccess = false
  var user: User? = null
}
```