# Room - How to correctly/efficiently make a query that needs data from another table to be performed

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata

**Context**

In The application i'm building there are two tables in my database:
- the first one filled with *USERS*:

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_User")
public class User {

@PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
private int id = 0;

@ColumnInfo(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "lastName")
private String lastName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "soprannome")
@NonNull
private String soprannome;
```

- in the second one i need to store couples of Users (organized by day), which i do saving the *ID* of the *USERS*:

```
   @Entity(tableName = "table_Couple")
   public class Couple {

   @ColumnInfo(name = "user_1")
   private Integer id_user_1;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "user_2")
   private Integer id_user_2;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "day")
   private int day;

   @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
   private Integer id;
```

Since the app is quite small i have a unique *ViewModel*, a *Repository*, that i use to organize calls to the *Dao* and perform actual calls to the Database

**My Concrete problem**

I need to obtain a *List* of *USERS* that appear in the *COUPLES* which have the same *DAY* and to put it in a *RecyclerView* to show them.
I have achieved a solution, which does not satisfy me, because, even with a small amount of data is slow and sloppy.

```
   private List<Couple> CoupleList;

   mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel.class);

    //Here we make the call to get all the couple **ON THE MAIN THREAD, WITHOUT USING LIVEDATA**
    couplesList = mWordViewModel.getCouplesByDay(fragmentDayId); 

    //Parsing from *list* of *COUPLES* to *list* of *INT*
    List<Integer> CouplesListParsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Couple eq : CouplesList){
        couplesListParsed.add(eq.getId_user_1());
        couplesListParsed.add(eq.getId_user_2());
    }

    // Add an observer on the LiveData
    mWordViewModel.getUsersById(CoupleListParsed).observe(this, new Observer<List<Users>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<User> users) {
            // Update the cached copy of the users in the adapter.
            adapter.setWords(users);
        }
    });
```

**Called Methods:**

```
    public List<Equipaggio> getCouplesByDay( Integer dayId) { return mRepository.getCouplesByDay(dayId); }


    public LiveData<List<Allievo>> getUsersById(List<Integer> id) { return mRepository.getUsersById(id); }
```

I'm pretty sure that my problems come from the Database Query *getEquipaggiByDay* on the main thread, but i can't figure how how to fix it, since making it LiveData doesn't seem to make sense and calling in on a new Thread doesn't really seem the solution to me.

**Actual Question**

So maybe my problem can maybe be reduced to: How to correctly/efficiently make a query that needs data from another table to be performed

It's my first question, so go easy on me, and if there is something missing in the code that i reported feel free to point it out.
Also i started fearing there could a little bit some bigger "architecture" problem or some bad practice in action, feel free to point those out too.

Comment: You probably want to define user 1 and 2 ids as foreign keys, and run a join query. Maybe one of the answers from this questions can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059942/return-type-for-android-room-joins

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I'll try and post my results.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to Pawel's answer i got to a better result, which i achieved thanks to this query:

```
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT * " +
        "FROM table_users AS al INNER JOIN table_couples AS eq" +
        " ON al.userId=eq.user_1 OR al.userId=eq.user_2" +
        " WHERE day=:dayId")
    LiveData<List<Allievo>> getUsersByCouplesByDay(Integer dayId) ;
```

To be able to perform this query i have modiefied my classes adding the needed Foreign Keys and indexes.